# Change colour of Calendar / System menu in Gnome Desktop

Tags: gnome, themes, customization, colors, appearance

Can anyone point out how I can go about changing the colours of the Shutdown menu and the Time/Calendar dropdowns within the gnome desktop, accessed from the top bar. Not sure what you'd officially call these, please see images as to what I'm referring to.

[image]

Ideally I'm looking to change the background colour of these menus, highlighted in yellow, and also change the accented blue colour, highlighted in green.

Comment: Hate to comment on my own thread to revive this, but anyone got any ideas on this? Can't seem to fine anything on it to help out.

Comment: Hi! You need to change the gnome-shell theme css file for this. There are no easy way to get around this

Answer (score 0):

For the volume bar i can modify it with this :

`-slider-active-background-color: rgb(180,208,81);`

I looked for to change the color of the active day too (like in your example) in the gnome calendar but i can't find it.

I find a way to change the focus background color on the other days but not the active and the same day number after or before (in your example the 6 may is in blue, but if you change months, like June, the 6th June will be in blue too) and i want to change the background color too.

I want to change the color of the size the windows gonna have when you split it (like in the picture), if anyone knows this please share.

[size focus windows color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UGhz.jpg)

Comment: i found for the last one, it's : `.tile-preview {
  background-color: rgba(180, 208, 81, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgb(180,208,81); }` but the calendar active day background still unknown

Answer (score 0):

Search for `#calendarArea{...}` in the theme's css file, maybe?

You want to make changes in `.calendar-day-base{...}` and `.calendar-today{...}` blocks.

In my case, all calendar related settings started from that `#calendarArea{...}` line and I could change a lot of things there. Play around and see what you like.